# Make changes on permission levels of a sharepoint online threshold exceeded document library

Tags: sharepoint

We have a sharepoint online site where there are 10 Doc Lib and user wants unique permissions on some document libraries out of which has exceeded its threshold limit, has 45125 items.
Could someone please suggest a way.

we couldnt do anything as it has thousands of files.
Is there a way in powershell to achieve this or should we proceed to split the doc library to several doc lib inorder to apply unique permissions?
If splitting is the only way, could you please let me know how we can do it.

Answer (score 0):

When a document library contains more than 100,000 items, you cannot break permissions inheritance on the entire library. Additionally, you cannot re-inherit permissions for the entire library.

However, you can still break inheritance on individual items within the library, up to the maximum number of unique permissions allowed in the list or library (which is typically 50,000, but it’s recommended to keep it below 5,000).

[image]

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits

It is recommended that you then place the new document in the new document library.

Comment: Did my response answer your question? If I misunderstand something, please let me know! If there is any other assistance i can provide, please feel free to let me know, i will do our best to help you.

Comment: The question author will not receive a notification if you comment under your own answer. Consider commenting under the question instead.